# WPF VS2022 cant check if targetype is Visibility

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, ivalueconverter

I have a *IValueConverter* that converts "null" to "Visible":

```
public class InverseNullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Visibility");
        
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This worked fine in *Visual Studio 2019*, however when i updated to *2022* i got error on every place that used this valueconverter. The first if-case ALWAYS returns true, no matter what input is given.

Why does not *"if (targetType != typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))"* work in VS 2022? What should i change to make it work?

Im using *.Net Framework 4.7.2.*

The error message that i receive is *XDG0066*, it has no text other than the text i provide in the throw *"The target must be a Visibility"*

An example of where i used the valueconverter:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Back" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ImageBack, Converter={StaticResource InverseNullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Just drop that type check. It is redundant. A Binding will tell you when its Converter returns an unexpected type.

Comment: It does not reproduce on VS2022.

Comment: [aybe]; Debugger gives me "XDG0066" with the error message i provided in the throw. 

[clemens]: I could just drop it, but i also would like to know why it isnt working when it was working in 2019. Out of curiosity but also so i learn and become more knowledgeable which might help me in the future. Right now it looks to me like it should work, but it doesnt, so there must be something im missing or dont understand. 

[emoacht]: Im using .Net Framework 4.7.2. Maybe you tested on core? Or a newer version?

Comment: It does not reproduce in WPF project of .NET Framework 4.7.2 on VS 2022 17.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem in the XAML designer, which seems to apply your converter in a context where the target type is not exactly `Visibility`.

Change your check to a more generally applicable expression, like

```
if (!targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Visibility)))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be assignable from Visibility");
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, but it still feels strange because the target was visiblity. I was using the valueconverter and got error on this line for example: <Rectangle x:Name="Back" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ImageBack, Converter={StaticResource InverseNullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

Comment: Try `if (targetType != typeof(Visibility)) MessageBox.Show(targetType.FullName);` to see what the designer does.

Comment: Messagebox shows: "System.Nullable'1[[System.Windows.Visibility, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=213bhef98234234n]]]".

I guess the problem is that the target is a nullable in the designer?

Comment: Seems so. No idea what exactly the designer is doing.